# Get time from a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to output time from my cell into a message box. However it keeps giving me decimals like 8.12. How to make it output in time form?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Background: Time (and dates) are stored as numbers internally. That's why VBA gives you a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.Text` rather than `.Value`:

```
Sub TimeInABox()
    MsgBox Range("a1").Text
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Can I turn the 8.23 into value within a code if I need to do more manipulations? Like text into value?

Comment: As otherwise it would turn it back into decimal within a code

Comment: @kjNums  Yes....using `.Text` gets a text value suitable for `MsgBox` .... you can always parse the text to get hours or minutes or seconds if that is what is required.